# GCP PubSub Java reactive client - should messages be acknowledged reactively?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using `com.google.cloud` / `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub` and building a reactive subscriber via the `PubSubReactiveFactory`'s `poll()` method. What I'm trying to understand is if the messages should be acknowledged within the reactive stream, or done in a `doOnNext`? The examples I've seen all show `ack()` (which returns a future) being called in `doOnNext` without waiting, but that concerns me.

For one, if `ack()` fails, then downstream operators won't know about it.

Secondly, calling `ack()` without waiting could potentially overwhelm the acknowledgement thread pool, but that's just a gut feeling, I'm not sure?

So the options I've tried are:

```
pubSubReactiveFactory.poll(subscriptionName, 100)
  .doOnNext(msg -> msg.ack())
  .subscribe();
```

or

```
pubSubReactiveFactory.poll(subscriptionName, 100)
  .flatMap(msg -> Mono.fromCompletionStage(msg.ack().completable()).thenReturn(msg))
  .subscribe();
```

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: I should note that the 2nd example (reactive, using flatMap) causes downstream operators to use the acknowledgement scheduler.